# How to make 2 divs overlap without absolute or margin to make website responsive?

Tags: html, css

Having trouble with positioning 2 divs to overlap each other without absolute or margin, cause i want my website to be responsive

```css
#review-title {
 width: 20%;
 height: 10%;
 position: relative;
 left: -5%;
 float: left;
#section {
 width: 20%;
 height: 80%;
 position: relative;
 left: 1%;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
    <div id="review-title" class="overlay ">
   <label class="w3-text-white underline" style=""><h2><b>text</b></h2></label>
  </div>
    <div class="section">
    <label id="" class="w3-text-white"><h4><b>text</b></h4></label>
    <label id="" class="w3-text-white">text</label>
    <br>
    <button id="" class="fa fa-arrow-right w3-btn w3-text-white light-overlay border-remove small-circle" style="border-radius: 50%; margin: 2% 0 -2% 0;" type="button" name="button"></button>
    </div>
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what are you trying to achieve and what does it have to do with responsiveness?
Why do you assume using absolute positioning or margins will make it not responsive?
I think using percentages is not a good idea in this case and maybe that is why it doesn't work as expected in different screen sizes for you.

Comment: when i use margin or absolute it makes the divs appear somewhere else instead of the place i put them, i want the divs to stay in place